# Load time for .wav vs .mp3 files

Tags: html, audio, load, mp3, wav

I figured this was an obvious question, but have yet to find a clear answer. I am asking specifically in-browser with regard to HTML5 audio elements. I have always assumed .wav would be slower because of the larger size. However, I have also heard that .mp3 files are slower because they must be decompressed.

Does anyone know the answer here? Strictly in terms of getting the page loaded up quickly, which should I use for my my audio elements?

Comment: You should never use .wav for pretty much anything, so, between the two, pick .mp3. (And yes, it would be way slower because of the file size. Decompression time is negligible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely pick mp3 because they are about 10x smaller than wav files of the same duration. As Ryan said, decompression times don't matter.